# Embed .jar file in html that require .txt file (java)

Tags: java, applet, acm-java-libraries

I'm using the acm libraries for my Java program, and I want to embed my program into my website via HTML. I have other .jar files embedded just fine in my website, by using the

```
<applet archive="file.jar, acm.jar"
code="main.class"
width=400 height=600 />
```

but have found that when embedded in HTML the program sort of freaks out and stops responding when it gets to the part where it should load the .txt file.

I remember vaguely my AP CompSci teacher telling us that java in web browsers blocked the import of .txt files, but I might be remembering incorrectly. Here is my java code below:

```
public NameSurferDataBase(String filename) {
    nameEntry = new HashMap<String, NameSurferEntry>();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while (true) {
            String line = rd.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;
            NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry(line);
            nameEntry.put(entry.getName().toUpperCase(), entry);                
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ErrorException(ex);
    }
}
```

So not only do I not know how to actually add the .txt file as something to use before it runs, I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: The file will need to be accessed by URL.  Is the text file inside `file.jar`, or is it a loose file on the server?

Comment: It is a loose file, would putting in inside my .jar file be helpful?

Comment: IT is almost as easy either way.  If the text file is the only file that applet will ever need to load, put it in the Jar.  If you might want to run the applet with different text files as input, loose on the server would be better.  You can specify a name to load in the applet parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when running applets, the security manager doesn't let you work with the filesystem (unless you specifically change the plugin settings which is a bad idea).  If you're just trying to read, put the file in your classpath, and use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String resource) to get the input stream instead.

Comment: My only question for you is where to put ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String resource). I'm not sure where to put that in my file read-in method.

Comment: @etufte252 etufte252 `getResourceAsStream()` returns an `InputStream` object.  There's also a class called `InputStreamReader`, which wraps an `InputStream` object.  Where do you think this `InputStreamReader` object could go? (I'm not giving you the answer because I want to help you learn)

Comment: @Michael I set it up like this 'InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename));' and changed my BufferedReader to be reading in 'is' and it is giving me an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResourceAsStream(String) from the type ClassLoader"

Comment: @etufte252 That's because `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` is static.  To get an instance of `ClassLoader`, do this: `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @etufte252 It's not a problem etufte